# How to initially show part of List view on Android

Tags: android

I have a sliding drawer implemented at the bottom of my layout. I want to show one cell as a default. I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours, so any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my XML file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@color/Red"
            android:text="Notification"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/LightGrey">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/notificationList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector_yellow"
            >
            </ListView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/dummieView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:background="@color/LightGrey" >
            </View>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@color/LightGrey"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ListView's `setSelection(int position)` method to scroll to a row. [See docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29).

Comment: hi set selection does not seem to work, I have tried to add it in like this, "ListView.setSelection(0);" but it doesnt seem have any effects.